# Display the file upload percentage in text box with progress bar on click browse button using jquery,javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On click browse button multiple files selected and multiple progress bar display but the value of only first textbox goes to 100% while other textbox values remain static.My code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.a{
display:none;
}
.input{
display:none;
}
.button {
    background: #25A6E1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#25A6E1),color-stop(100%,#188BC0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#25A6E1',endColorstr='#188BC0',GradientType=0);
    padding:8px 13px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #1A87B9;
    width:227px !important;
}   


</style>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" class="button" id="files" name="files" multiple><br/>
        <div id="progress-wpr">
        <div class="filename"></div>
        <progress class='a'  max=100 value=0></progress>
        <input type="text" value="0" class="input"  max="100" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit"  value="Upload" class="button" style="margin-top:56px;width:77px !important" >
    </form>


    <script>

    var selDiv = "";

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

    function init() {
        document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    }

    function handleFileSelect(e) {

        if(!e.target.files) return;

        var files = e.target.files;

         for(var i=1; i<files.length; i++) {
            var progress = document.createElement("progress");
            progress.setAttribute('class','a');
            progress.setAttribute('max','100');
            progress.setAttribute('value','0');
            var filename = document.createElement("div");
            var text=document.createElement("input");
            text.setAttribute('class','input');
            text.setAttribute('value','10');
             text.setAttribute('max','100');
            filename.setAttribute('class','filename');
            document.getElementById('progress-wpr').appendChild(filename);
            document.getElementById('progress-wpr').appendChild(progress);
             document.getElementById('progress-wpr').appendChild(text);
        }


        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
        var filename = document.getElementsByClassName('filename');
          var textname = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
        for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {

            var f = files[i];
            var p=elements[i];
            var t=textname[i];

            filename[i].innerHTML = f.name;
            p.style.display='block';
               t.style.display='block';
            setInterval(update_progress, 1500);
             setInterval(updatetextbox, 1500);
        }

    }
function update_progress(){
     var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');

    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var p=elements[i];


        var a=p.value;
        a=a+10; //alert(a)// infinite number of times sum 
if(a==110)  //if this part add then see
break;       
        p.value=a; //alert(p.value);

    }
}
function updatetextbox(){


    var textt=document.getElementsByClassName('input');
    //alert(textt.length);  //any alert in this doc display right value but n no times
    for(var i=0; i<textt.length; i++) {

        var tt=textt[i];
        alert(textt[i]);
        var a=tt.value;
        c=parseInt(a)+parseInt("10");

if(parseInt(c) < 0 || isNaN(c)) 
        return 0; 
    else if(parseInt(c) > 100) 
        return tt.value=100; 
    else return  tt.value=c;


    }
}



    </script>

</body>
</html>

I have to display the file upload percentage in a textbox with progress bar.
```

Comment: how you getting the file uploading percentage ?

Comment: first dynamically adding textbox and dynamically incrementing its value by 10 using updatetextbox() function

Comment: hey hello, just to let you know that i'm giving it a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside this for statement:

```
for(var i=0; i<textt.length; i++) {
    var tt=textt[i];
    alert(textt[i]);
    var a=tt.value;
    c=parseInt(a)+parseInt("10");

    if(parseInt(c) < 0 || isNaN(c)) 
        return 0;    // <---------------------------- here 
    else if(parseInt(c) > 100) 
        return tt.value=100; 
    else return  tt.value=c;
}
```

When it reach the return statement the function ends and the next item on the for loop is never reached so only the first element in the for is added.

Also when you use the function setInterVal() you must also use clearInterval() to prevent the function going and going unitil the window is closed, i leave you an example of your code with the applied corrections for you to try them.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.a{
display:none;
}
.input{
display:none;
}
.button {
    background: #25A6E1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#25A6E1),color-stop(100%,#188BC0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#25A6E1',endColorstr='#188BC0',GradientType=0);
    padding:8px 13px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #1A87B9;
    width:227px !important;
}   


</style>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" class="button" id="files" name="files" multiple><br/>
        <div id="progress-wpr">
        <div class="filename"></div>
        <progress class='a'  max=100 value=0></progress>
        <input type="text" value="0" class="input"  max="100" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit"  value="Upload" class="button" style="margin-top:56px;width:77px !important" >
    </form>


    <script>

    var selDiv = "";
    var updateProcessInterval;
    var updateTextBoxInterval;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

    function init() {
        document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    }

    function handleFileSelect(e) {

        if(!e.target.files) return;

        var files = e.target.files;

         for(var i=1; i<files.length; i++) {
            var progress = document.createElement("progress");
            progress.setAttribute('class','a');
            progress.setAttribute('max','100');
            progress.setAttribute('value','0');
            var filename = document.createElement("div");
            var text=document.createElement("input");
            text.setAttribute('class','input');
            text.setAttribute('value','10');
             text.setAttribute('max','100');
            filename.setAttribute('class','filename');
            document.getElementById('progress-wpr').appendChild(filename);
            document.getElementById('progress-wpr').appendChild(progress);
             document.getElementById('progress-wpr').appendChild(text);
        }


        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
        var filename = document.getElementsByClassName('filename');
          var textname = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
        for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {

            var f = files[i];
            var p=elements[i];
            var t=textname[i];

            filename[i].innerHTML = f.name;
            p.style.display='block';
               t.style.display='block';
            updateProcessInterval = setInterval(update_progress, 1500);
            updateTextBoxInterval = setInterval(updatetextbox, 1500);
        }

    }
function update_progress(){
     var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');

    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var p=elements[i];


        var a=p.value;
        a=a+10; //alert(a)// infinite number of times sum 
        if(a>100){  //if this part add then see
               clearInterval(updateProcessInterval);  
        }       
        p.value=a; //alert(p.value);

    }
}
function updatetextbox(){
    var textt=document.getElementsByClassName('input');
    //alert(textt.length);  //any alert in this doc display right value but n no times
    for(var i=0; i<textt.length; i++) {

        var tt=textt[i];
        //alert(textt[i]);
        var a=tt.value;
        c=parseInt(a)+parseInt("10");

        if(parseInt(c) > 100) {
                clearInterval(updateTextBoxInterval);
                return;
        }   else if(!(parseInt(c) < 0 || isNaN(c))){
            tt.value=c;
        }


    }
}



    </script>

</body>
</html>

I have to display the file upload percentage in a textbox with progress bar.
```

Comment: is always a pleasure :)